# Is there more the right way to compare between present date and a deadline?

Tags: php, date

Is there more the right way to compare between present date and a deadline?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$deadline = date('2016-04-26 23:59:59');
$deadline = strtotime($deadline);
$now = strtotime("now");

if ($now > $deadline) {
    echo 'Deadline has passed.';
} elseif ($now === $deadline) {
    echo 'The same time.';
} else {
    echo 'You have time';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Do you get expected results?

Comment: I tried it, and it work. But is there a more right way to do it?

Comment: Would you show me? Please?

Comment: Why are you calling `date()` when setting `$deadline`? It's just returning the same string, so it's the same as `$deadline = '2016-04-26 23:59:59';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've given should work as intended, but is somewhat "older" style. The "modern" version would be using the [`DateTime` family of objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

```
$tz = new DateTimezone('Asia/Jakarta');
$deadline = new DateTime('2016-04-26 23:59:59', $tz);
$now = new DateTime('now');

if ($now > $deadline) {
    echo 'Deadline has passed.';
} elseif ($now === $deadline) {
    echo 'The same time.';
} else {
    echo 'You have time';
}
```

One specific advantage of this approach is that you do not have to globally modify the default timezone.

Comment: I like it, it's very clear.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the right way to compare between present date and a deadline?

IMO **no**, you should use the [DateTime class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), i.e.:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$deadLine = new DateTime('2016-04-26 23:59:59');
$deadLine->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$now = new DateTime();

if ($now  > $deadLine ) {
    echo 'Deadline has passed.';
} elseif ($now  == $deadLine) {
    echo 'Same time';
} else {
   $interval = $now->diff($deadLine);
   echo 'You have ' . $interval->format('%R%a days');
}
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/VsiJ45)